# Accordion menu animation sequencing

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to create a accordion menu in angular using css3 transitions.
I'm facing issues in sequencing the animations. In the current page when I click on "Arrest" in the menu it first expands and then any other currently open element( in this case "general") collapses. How can both the animations work at the same time ?

```
app.directive('menuaccordion', function() {
return {
    restrict : 'A',


    link : function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        var $el = angular.element(elem);
        if($el.hasClass('app-nav-menu-lv1')) {
          var name = elem.attr('data-name')
          scope.$on('hidelevel1', function(e, data){
              if(data != name) {
                var container = $el.next()
                if(container.hasClass('in')) {
                  container.removeClass('in');
                }
              }
        });
        }

      scope.$on('hidelevel2', function(e, data){
         console.log($el)
      });

        elem.on('click', function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          var container = angular.element(elem.next());
          if(container.hasClass('in')) {  //is expanded
            container.removeClass('in'); 
          }else{                          //is collapsed
            container.addClass('in');
            var name = elem.attr('data-name')
            if($el.hasClass('app-nav-menu-lv1')) {
              scope.$broadcast('hidelevel1', name);
            }else if($el.hasClass('app-nav-menu-lv2')) {
              scope.$broadcast('hidelevel2', name);
            }

          }

        });

    }
 }
});
```

Plnkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/Sreh0yIDvq4oy4Nhvlea?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In reality both animations are happening at the same time. The problem is that you have set a `max-height` of `1000px`, so what it's happening is that while the `ul` that it's being opened starts displaying, the  height of the one that it's supposed to hide is being reduced, but you can't notice it because it's too high and it takes a long time to start hiding the content. So, maybe you could change the `max-height` to `220px`, like this:

```
.collapse.in {
    max-height:220px;
}
```

Also, I've had a look at your directive, and I think that it could be improved quite a bit, like this (it's just a suggestion, nothing to do with your problem):

```
app.directive('menuaccordion', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict : 'A',
        compile:function (elem, attrs){
          var aTag = elem.find('a');
          var itemName = elem.attr('data-name');
          aTag.attr('ng-click', "select('" + itemName + "')");
          elem.next().attr('ng-class', "{in: selectedItem=='" + itemName + "'}");

          return function(scope, elem, attrs) {
              scope.select=function(name){
                scope.$parent.selectedItem=scope.$parent.selectedItem==name?'':name;
              };
            };
        }
    };
});
```

## [Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/P3foGjZiMz0ClSLL30ML?p=preview)